# LCD display connection and power supply

Tags: lcd, rca

I found an old car DVD player, figured I might try and use the LCDs for something else, most likely with a raspberry pi. They're 4.5" displays, Prime View Model #PW045XS2. I'm thinking adding an RCA connector to the driver would be the easiest feat, the thing I'm not so confident on is the power.
I found the specs for the DVD player as a whole here: http://www.diagramasde.com/diagramas/otros2/PVS1950D[1].pdf Page 16 has the monitor diagram.

I want to confirm one thing - If I just connect an RCA port to the VIDEO/VGND pins, should that work or is there something else I need to do?

And I want to ask another - What kind of power supply do I need to connect? I'm fairly sure it needs 5V, but not sure on the amperage.
I did try a 5V 500mA supply (what I had lying around) and was able to get at least some of the backlight on.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to measure it while it's connected to the rest of the player. Use a multimeter to measure the supply voltage and current draw on the power connector.